# using FileInputStream and FileOutputStream

Tags: java, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

Hi I had a couple of questions about using the FileInputStream and FileOutputStream classes.

1. How would FileInputStream objects locate a file it is trying to read in?
2. Where would FileOutputStream save a file to?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html); both take strings or files in their constructors.

Comment: @radiodef nope. just saw it in an example.

Answer (score 1):

Strange question and I will give a strange answer.

First part: don't use either, use `Files`:

```
final Path src = Paths.get("some/file/somewhere");
final InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(src);
// ...
final Path dst = Paths.get("another/file");
final OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(dst);
```

Note that `Path` objects are in essence abstract: nothing guarantees that they point to a valid entry. If they don't, the `Files` methods above will throw a `NoSuchFileException` (file does not exist), or an `AccessDeniedException` (sorry mate, you can't do that), or any relevant exception.

---

Second part: `File*Stream`

The basics are the same: if you are stuck with Java 6 you have to use `File` instead of `Path`, but `File` is as abstract as `Path` is; it may, or may not, point to a valid location.

When you issue:

```
final String dst = "/some/file";
new FileOutputStream(dst);
```

internally, `FileOutputStream` will create a `File` object; which means the above is equivalent to:

```
final String dst = "/some/file";
final File f = new File(dst);
new FileOutputStream(f);
```

---

Conclusion: no, `File*Stream` does not know per se whether a file exists as long as it does not try to open it. `Path`s as well as `File`s are completely abstract until you try and do something with them.

And do yourself a favour: use the new file API which Java 7+ provides. Have you ever tried to initiate a `FileInputStream` with a `File` which exists but you cannot read from? `FileNotFoundException`. Meh. `Files.newInputStream()` will at least throw a meaningful exception...

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you simply pass the file object to the stream instantiations.

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
BufferedInputStream is2 = new BufferedInputStream(is);
BufferedOutputStream os2 = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
```

Also consider using Printwriter for the output stream when you are working with text files.

Answer (score 0):

**About Streams:**
Streams are objects that allow an app to communicate with other programs.

To directly answer your question, in Java, here is how I would use the Streams.

```
//You need to import a few classes before you begin
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
```

You can declare them this way

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("filename.txt"); //this file should be located within the project folder
```

For output stream, it can be accessed a similar way:

```
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("filename.txt"); //this file should be located within the project folder
```

**More Information:**

I recommend using a PrintWriter when trying to write to text files. To do this, you would implement the following:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
```

Then use this to write to the file:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(OUTPUT_STREAM);
```

I also recommend using the Scanner class when reading in user data:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Then use this to read the input:

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(INPUT_STREAM); //now you can access this data by using methods such as nextInt, nextDouble, etc...
```